# How to do web scraping in python running raspberry pi lite os?

Tags: python, web-scraping, raspberry-pi

Help is needed to track the prices of a product from websites using python running in raspberry pi lite 64-bit os. I tried two approaches without success.

Below are the OS and version details of Python, beautiful soup, and scrapy that are used for my web scraping

```
$ uname -m
  aarch64

$ python --version
  Python 3.7.3

$ scrapy version
  Scrapy 2.5.1

>>> bs4.__version__
'4.10.0'
```

**Approach 1: requests_html**

```
webscrapping.py

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession


emailcontent = "Subject: My daily digest \n"


def web_scrape_function(htmlid, emailcontent, classselector, webrequesturl):
    i = 1
    session = HTMLSession()
    r = session.get(webrequesturl)
    r.html
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    result = soup.find_all(htmlid, attrs={'class': classselector})
    r.session.close()
    for eachresult in result:
        emailcontent += ("%s- " % i)
        emailcontent += eachresult.text.strip()
        emailcontent += "\n"
        i += 1

    print(emailcontent)
    session.close()


# Endy pillow


web_scrape_function("span", emailcontent, "original-price",
                    "https://ca.endy.com/products/the-customizable-pillow?gclid=CjwKCAiAn5uOBhADEiwA_pZwcDx8pC80pUaaiLTsHof33OPqrUOEDZ3v-ogIcdJ5PdSrvcR-WxVGSxoCWkUQAvD_BwE&size=king")
```

*Output*

```
$ python3 webscrapping.py 

Subject: My daily digest 
1- ${{this.numberWithCommas(this.formatPrice(this.selected_variant.price))}}
    $
2- ${{this.numberWithCommas(this.formatPrice(this.selected_variant.price))}}
    $
3- Out of Stock

${{formatPrice(size.price)}}
```

**Approach 2: Scrapy**

myspider.py

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "peppe8o"
    start_urls = [
        'https://ca.endy.com/products/the-customizable-pillow?gclid=CjwKCAiAn5uOBhADEiwA_pZwcDx8pC80pUaaiLTsHof33OPqrUOEDZ3v-ogIcdJ5PdSrvcR-WxVGSxoCWkUQAvD_BwE&size=king',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for prices in response.css('div.flex-container div.desktop-product-price'):
            yield {
                'price': prices.css('div.flex-container span.original-price::text').get(),
            }
```

*Output*

```
$ scrapy runspider myspider.py -o peppe8o.json

$ cat peppe8o.json
  [
   {"price": "\n    "}
  ]
```

I am unable to get the value of $95 in both the above 2 approaches. The above two approaches seem to be working fine for some static websites, which makes me believe that I am running into the issue only with dynamic web pages that use javascript rendering. Please suggest corrections or alternate code, for achieving what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Right.  Neither `requests` nor `scrapy` have a Javascript interpreter.  All you get is the static HTML as delivered.  If you need Javascript interpreted, then you have to use a real browser, and that generally means Selenium.

Comment: Thanks. I will post a separate question on how to install and run selenium headless in aarch64. I see only guides for x86, x64, amd64, arm64.